# Java Collections's sort w/ comparator specifics

Tags: swing, sorting, collections

I'm using a comparator to sort through an IRC user list and characters like `[` and `_` precede `@`. How do I prevent this? I want the users beginning with those characters to be among the regular users. The comparator as it looks now:

```
public class UserListSorter implements Comparator<String> { 

// Get the Collator for the current locale.
private Collator collator = Collator.getInstance();     

@Override                                               // The comparator that implements the abovementioned.
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {                                  // Compare these users.
    int compare = compareString(o1.substring(0, 2), o2.substring(0, 2));    // Get the user group of the users (@,+,())
    if (compare == 0) {                                                     // If both are in the same group, sort by
        return compareString(o1, o2);                                       // their name only.
    }
    return compare;                                                         // Else, return a positive value stating
}                                                                           // that @ and + holds a higher value  than ().

private int compareString(String o1, String o2) {                           // Compares the users alphabetically, ignoring small
    return collator.compare(o1, o2);                                        // and capital letters. Used as a basis for sorting algo.
}

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: "How do I prevent this?" but what is the behaviour you desire? Put username that begin with '@' before anything else?

Comment: Yes, this is the normal behaviour of an IRC user list.

Comment: hmm ... how is this related to swing?

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but should do the trick:

```
if  (o1.charAt(0) == '@' && o2.charAt(0) != '@') return 2;
else if  (o1.charAt(0) != '@' && o2.charAt(0) == '@') return -2;
else if  (o1.charAt(0) == '+' && o2.charAt(0) != '+') return 1;
else if  (o1.charAt(0) != '+' && o2.charAt(0) == '+') return -1;
else return o1.compareTo(o2);
```

Edit: current behaviour is that names starting with `@` > `+` > any other.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the second line shouldn't be `else if  (o1.charAt(0) != '@' && o2.charAt(0) == '@') return -1;` ? What about `+`? This seems to be onle a partial answer.

Comment: Yeah, it has to be '==' (it's quite obvious that the third case is the one with both equals/not-equals). I don't know what you mean about '+'; if it's another IRC symbol, the OP didn't mention it but it should be trivial to include it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I though this was general knowledge for programmers (no offence). Also, the solution presented didn't work but it made me to better understand how a comparator works.

Comment: What was general knowledge? The IRC symbols? It's been a while since I used IRC chats, yeah. Exactly, what didn't work of the solution (aside from the aformentioned mistake)? I'll edit to include the + sign anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend introducing a bit higher level of abstraction here and taking a bit more OO aproach.

Suppose we create an object representing our IRC user, lets call it `IRCUser`:

```
class IRCUser implements Comparable<IRCUser>
{
     private IRCRole ircRole;
     private String nickName; //full nickname

     public int compareTo(IRCUser otherUser)
     {
        //Implementation
     }
}
```

and then create an enum describing a role a user can be awarded on a particular IRC channel, something like:

```
public enum IRCRole
{
    STANDARD("", 2), PRIVILEDGED("+",1) , OP("@",0)

    IRCRole(String nickNamePrefix, int priority)
    {
        this.nickNamePrefix = nickNamePrefix;
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    private String nickNamePrefix;
    private int priority;

}
```

Now, the compareTo method of our IRCUser might start of by comparing the role of `this` user (the role `priority` to be precise) with the role of the user passed as an argument and after that do simple String comparison. How about that?

Comment: Yeah it could probably work, but I will not be trying it as this was a deliverable that is now long over due. Thanks for you suggestion and your time. 

For the record, the solution mentioned above did not work at all. Users with @ preceding their became scattered all over the place, and we just ended up with what I've posted in the first post (incomplete).